# Implementing a C API in D

Tags: c, d

So there's plenty of information about calling C APIs from within D, but how about the reverse?  What do you need to do to write a library in D that works like a normal C shared library?  Here's an easy case:

main.c

```
extern int foo(int x);
void main() {
    printf("foo(5)=%d\n",foo(5));
}
```

foo.d

```
extern(C)
{
    int foo(int x)
    {
         return x*x;
    }
}
```

Naively trying to build and link these with gcc and dmd just results in linker errors.

Linking with gcc main.o foo.o:

```
doFoo.o: In function `no symbol':
doFoo.d:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `_Dmodule_ref'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Linking with dmd main.o foo.o:

```
/usr/lib64/libphobos2.a(deh2_2eb_525.o): In function `_D2rt4deh213__eh_finddataFPvZPS2rt4deh213DHandlerTable':
src/rt/deh2.d:(.text._D2rt4deh213__eh_finddataFPvZPS2rt4deh213DHandlerTable+0xa): undefined reference to `_deh_beg'
src/rt/deh2.d:(.text._D2rt4deh213__eh_finddataFPvZPS2rt4deh213DHandlerTable+0x14): undefined reference to `_deh_beg'
src/rt/deh2.d:(.text._D2rt4deh213__eh_finddataFPvZPS2rt4deh213DHandlerTable+0x1e): undefined reference to `_deh_end'
src/rt/deh2.d:(.text._D2rt4deh213__eh_finddataFPvZPS2rt4deh213DHandlerTable+0x46): undefined reference to `_deh_end'
/usr/lib64/libphobos2.a(lifetime.o): In function `_D2rt8lifetime18_sharedStaticCtor9FZv':
src/rt/lifetime.d:(.text._D2rt8lifetime18_sharedStaticCtor9FZv+0x15): undefined reference to `_tlsend'
src/rt/lifetime.d:(.text._D2rt8lifetime18_sharedStaticCtor9FZv+0x29): undefined reference to `_tlsstart'
/usr/lib64/libphobos2.a(thread_a3_258.o): In function `_D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFPFZvmZC4core6thread6Thread':
src/core/thread.d:(.text._D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFPFZvmZC4core6thread6Thread+0x2b): undefined reference to `_tlsend'
src/core/thread.d:(.text._D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFPFZvmZC4core6thread6Thread+0x36): undefined reference to `_tlsstart'
/usr/lib64/libphobos2.a(thread_a3_258.o): In function `_D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFDFZvmZC4core6thread6Thread':
src/core/thread.d:(.text._D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFDFZvmZC4core6thread6Thread+0x28): undefined reference to `_tlsend'
src/core/thread.d:(.text._D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFDFZvmZC4core6thread6Thread+0x33): undefined reference to `_tlsstart'
/usr/lib64/libphobos2.a(thread_a3_258.o): In function `_D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFZC4core6thread6Thread':
src/core/thread.d:(.text._D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFZC4core6thread6Thread+0x26): undefined reference to `_tlsend'
src/core/thread.d:(.text._D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFZC4core6thread6Thread+0x31): undefined reference to `_tlsstart'
/usr/lib64/libphobos2.a(thread_a0_713.o): In function `thread_entryPoint':
src/core/thread.d:(.text.thread_entryPoint+0x36): undefined reference to `_tlsend'
src/core/thread.d:(.text.thread_entryPoint+0x41): undefined reference to `_tlsstart'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

Comment: Um, don't leave us hangin'... what are the errors?

Comment: The linker errors are: `foo.o: In function 'no symbol':
foo.d:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to '_Dmodule_ref'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is about using  **D static libraries** from **C**.
Yes, this is a bit off topic, but shared libraries for **Windows** are described in D's documentation (http://www.d-programming-language.org/dll.html) and for **Linux** are still under construction (http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/changelog.html). Working examples for both systems are attached.

- **Win32**: dmd+dmc works great. *Example*: [test_d_from_c_win32.zip](http://deoma-cmd.ru/files/other/test_d_from_c_win32.zip)
- **Linux32**: dmd adds some required stuff once it has found D main function, so D's main is needed (tested for dmd2+gcc on Linux32).
  It's linkage name is "_Dmain" and it will not be mixed with C's one (real "main").
  So one can just add the file `dfakemain.d` with text `void main(){}`.
  `dmd -c dfakemain.d` will create dfakemain.o with missing symbols. Link it with your object files and you will be happy. *Example*: [test_d_from_c_linux32.tar.gz](http://deoma-cmd.ru/files/other/test_d_from_c_linux32.tar.gz)

Comment: Hmm the linux method worked for me, but it still has some issues.  One being that it requires you to used dmd as your linker.  Is there some library that you could link against to resolve that issue?
Second, it seems like sticking in a fake main makes the library not also usable a D library, and possibly incompatible with other libraries that are using the same trick.

Comment: No it doesn't _require you to used dmd as your linker_ (and it can't, because dmd can't link, it just calls an external linker to do it). You just need to link with `dfakemain.o`. In my linux example gcc is used as a "caller of the linker". _Is there some library that you could link against to resolve that issue?_
Yes. It is `dfakemain.o`. In example, it isn't linked with D library (dlibrary.o) and it shouldn't. It should be linked once per executable if it use some D libraries.

Comment: Ah, I see my answer was actually in the build.sh of your example.  I was missing the -lrt -lphobos2 -lpthread -lm part of your solution.

Answer (score 9):

According to a quick glance at the [compiler source code](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/blob/master/src/backend/elfobj.c#L2925), `_Dmodule_ref` is the linked list of module constructors. To fix the issue, add this to your `main.c`:

```
void* _Dmodule_ref;
```

The program now links and runs fine.

<sup>(At least, that's how I think it works.)</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you actually have to make a call to initialize the D runtime rather than just fixing the linker errors, but I've never actually done this before, so I don't know. I know that some folks in the newsgroup have been doing it for Windows GUI apps though, so _someone_ there knows exactly what to do. I just posted a question about it in D.Learn. Hopefully, someone there who's done it will respond here.

Comment: Yep, if you want fancy stuff like memory allocations or even static constructors then you obviously need to set it up :) but if you'd like to use D as a better C, this could work.

Comment: This does seem to work for this case, but I'll want to give it a more thorough shakedown.  Do you know what this symbol is supposed to be doing?

Comment: As far as I can see, `_Dmodule_ref` is the head of a linked list of module information. At initialization, the module adds a structure with the module's info to the list, so that once runtime initialization (memory management, etc.) has completed, the runtime can call the module static/shared constructors. (At least, that's how I think it works.)

Answer (score 6):

If gcc is compiling as C++, the default linkage used for the extern will be C++, not C. Try this instead:

```
extern "C" int foo(int x);
```

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your D syntax. There is a paragraph confirming your approach here: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/interfaceToC.html

Comment: Nope, not compiling as C++.  Just plain old gcc -c main.c